# How to change network device operations table safety?

Tags: linux, concurrency, network-programming, kernel-module

In Linux a network device is presented by struct net_device. One of fields of this structure is pointer to struct net_device_ops presenting the table of network device operations.

I'm writing kernel module which is network packets filter.
How can I safety replace those table (I'm afraid concurrency)?

Comment: Have you looked into whether netfilter would work for your use case? It would be much simpler than fiddling with per-device structures.

Comment: I write course project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly agree with Joel answer. You better try to use the kernel netfiler API for filtering traffic. The netfilter API provides five hooks into various points along the packet traversal in the Linux kernel networking stack, and you need to find out which one is required for registering a callack which will perform the required filtering. Sometimes more than one hook is required. There is documentation about it in the web.